# Adding field and calculating field values based on a current field using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, calculate-values

I created a new numeric field (`FloodValues`) and need to populate that field based on values from an existing text field (`ClassName`).  There are seven different values in `ClassName` field so I need to add values 0-6 to the new field.

Basically need a conditional statement that will convert these text values to numerics:

```
If ClassName = Very Rare then 0
else
If ClassName = Rare then 1
....
If ClassName = Very Frequent then 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a simple if/then/else logic in a field calculate tool, see examples in [How To: Use IF statements in the Field Calculator](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022370).